# NSDate is one hour behind user's local time

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsdate, nstimezone

I currently store dates in Parse, based on the US/Eastern time zone. However, when I get the objects from Parse and set their date properties, the time is always displayed as one hour earlier than the expected time.

I believe this is a result of daylight savings time, but I am unsure how to correct the issue without hardcoding the addition of an extra hour.

```
var objectDate = object.createdAt! // object is from Parse query
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar() // I am in Pacific timezone
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, M/d, h:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "US/Eastern") // date is 8 am Eastern time
var formattedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(objectDate)
// formattedDate prints as 4 am, but should be 5 am
```

Comment: You should always store dates in GMT...

Comment: Save your dates as NSTimeIntervals (doubles) then convert them to dates for display. How are you displaying formattedDate?

Comment: So if I set dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT"), that means that I am setting the date from Parse to have the GMT timezone. Am I right? Then, how would I make sure that that date is converted to the user's time zone on their device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to think about dates as not having a timezone as part of them. What I mean is, when you say "Save the time and day right now" the NSDate object should use UTC time, because it really *doesn't matter*. When you go to look at the date, you *view* it from a certain timezone or format perspective:

So, it could be like this:

```
//this saves the date as NOW, whenever it is called
var date = NSDate()
//it doesn't matter what timezone you want it to save in, because it always
//saves in a way that it KNOWS when it occurred

//when I want to view the value of the date from a "PST" timezone perspective
//I need to use an NSDateFormatter to set my point of view for the date
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "PST") //sets formatter to show what PST zone is
formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a z" //formats the time to show as 07:30 PST

//now that we have the date formatted, we could do something like set a label to it
@IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
dateLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

So, as you see above, the date isn't really saved as any particular timezone. It is simply saved in a way that the code can figure out the exact time/date. You then view the date however you want when you refer to it and use an NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Charlie for the help. And to solve my issue with the one hour time difference, I added an if statement to check if the user is currently in daylight savings time. If the user is, then we add one hour to the current time:

```
if (NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone().daylightSavingTime == true) {
    var newDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitHour, value: +1, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))!
}
```